# Increasing Processing Time

Tags: c#

I have a piece of code which compares and validate dates.

**Problem:**

This code is taking too much time during execution. When i comment this code the execution takes much less time. From this i can understand this code has some overhead in it. Please make suggestions to improve efficiency of this code.

```
DateTime regDate;
DateTime dob;

extractDate(buffer[5], buffer[6], out regDate, out dob);

private void extractDate(string date, string rDate, out DateTime regDate, out DateTime dob)
{
    if (date == "")     // Date of birth is not given;
    {
        regDate = getStandardDate(rDate);   // MM/DD/YYYY
        dob = regDate.AddYears(-18);
    }
    else
    {
        dob = getStandardDate(date);
    }

    if (rDate == "")
    {
        dob = getStandardDate(date);
        regDate = dob.AddYears(18);
    }
    else
    {
        regDate = getStandardDate(rDate);
    }
} 

private DateTime getStandardDate(string date)
{
    bool checkDate = isValidDate(date);
    if (checkDate)
    {
        IFormatProvider culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-gb", true);
        DateTime dt;
        if (karachiDateFormat)
        {
            dt = DateTime.Parse(date);
        }
        else
        {
            dt = DateTime.Parse(date, culture);
        }


        return dt.Date;
    }
    else
    {
        return DateTime.Now.Date;
    }
}

private bool isValidDate(string date)
{
    IFormatProvider culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-gb", true);
    DateTime Ttime;
    if (!karachiDateFormat)
    {
        Ttime = DateTime.Parse(date, culture);
    }
    else
    {
        Ttime = DateTime.Parse(date);
    }

    date = string.Empty;
    date = Ttime.Date.ToShortDateString();
    string[] splitDate = date.Split('/');

    int day = Int32.Parse(splitDate[1]);
    int month, year;
    month = Int32.Parse(splitDate[0]);

    year = Int32.Parse(splitDate[2]);
    DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
    if ((day > 0 && day < 32) && (month > 0 && month <= 12) && (year > 1950 && year < time.Year))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you're wondering why it's faster when you comment all your code out?

Comment: Profile the code. Find out what exactly is causing the slowdowns. What do you mean by too slow? How do you know?

Comment: @Osiris: No, he/she just says that by seeing that it was faster after commenting out, the commented out code must be the culprit for the slow-down.

Comment: (wild guessing) When you comment out the call to extractDate, `regDate` and `dob` do not get set, which may lead to a speedup somewhere else. As for the code you've shown, I do not see any significant flaws concerning execution time.

Comment: @O. R. Mapper, please explain what do you mean by 'Commenting out' ?? I'm using this part of code in a project.

Comment: Why are you parsing a string as a date, converting it to a string, splitting it, parsing the splits as integers, and checking the integers, then returning a boolean to say whether the integers were valid, and if so reparsing the date? If you've got a lot of code like this around, no wonder your program is slow.

Comment: There are lots of superfluous parses and string splits, but nothing that would cause a noticable performance difference, except if you are calling these methods very often.

Comment: @ahmii321: You wrote yourself that you have tentatively transformed parts of that code into comments. I was just rephrasing that, hoping that I didn't misunderstand your question.

Comment: I think that's exactly why you have `DateTime.TryParse`, check that out and modify your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can speed up your code by changing the isValidDate method.
From what I understand you validate the text if it matches the date pattern. I would try to completely remove this method and replace `DateTime.Parse` in your getStandardTime with `DateTime.TryParse` This will take care of both validation and parsing. See here [DateTime.TryParse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx)

If you need some validation of your date, than do this with DateTime structure, not with string repesentation.

Also you are parsing two dates (date and rDate). maybe using [Parallel.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992634.aspx) could help, but I am not sure about this.

```
    private void extractDate(string date, string rDate, out DateTime regDate, out DateTime dob)
    {
        Parallel.Invoke(
            () =>
            {
                if (date == "")     // Date of birth is not given;
                {
                    regDate = getStandardDate(rDate);   // MM/DD/YYYY
                    dob = regDate.AddYears(-18);
                }
                else
                {
                    dob = getStandardDate(date);
                }
            },
        () =>
        {

            if (rDate == "")
            {
                dob = getStandardDate(date);
                regDate = dob.AddYears(18);
            }
            else
            {
                regDate = getStandardDate(rDate);
            }
        });
    }

    private DateTime getStandardDate(string date)
    {
        IFormatProvider culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-gb", true);
        DateTime dt;
        if (karachiDateFormat)
        {
            if (!DateTime.TryParse(date, out dt))
                dt = DateTime.Now.Date;
        }
        else
        {
            if (!DateTime.TryParse(date, culture, out dt))
                dt = DateTime.Now.Date;
        }
    }
```